# When e.g. a star falls into a black hole would that part of the event horizon extend for a while?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, gravitational-redshift

When e.g. a star falls into a black hole would a part of the event horizon at that point extend for a while due to extra gravity due to the incomming star? And when the star starts to disappear even we would see that in slow motion how fast would that conjectured extruded part of the event horizon disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a black hole's event horizon will extend, because the way the black hole get bigger is by swallowing objects with a lot of mass. Once the black hole expands, the event horizon will expand as well. And after the star goes in, the part of the event horizon that is expanded, will shrink, but the event horizon will be a little bit bigger as the black hole gained mass.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking if the event horizon will deform towards the star due to the changing gravitational potential. Supposing we are dealing with a Schwarzschild black hole, they are asking if spherical symmetry will be broken and the EH becomes more oblong in some direction. I believe the answer is yes due to the star deforming the metric in its vicinity, but I do not feel up for figuring it out in detail and posting an answer. Hopefully someone with more experience and confidence can elaborate.